# Big array and MemoryError: Unable to allocate memory (in Python)

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a predictive model using linear regression with a dataset that has 157,673 entries.

The data (in a csv file) is in such format:

```
Timestamp,Signal_1,Signal_2,Signal_3,Signal_4,Signal_5
2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
```

My current code:

```py
    filename = 'test.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename , parse_dates=['Timestamp'], header=0)
    df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']))
    u, v, w, x, y, z = df.values.T
    
    X = np.asarray([v, w, x, y, z])
    Y = np.asarray([u, u, u, u, u])
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)
    
    lineReg = LinearRegression()
    lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('Score: ', lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
    print('Weights: ', lineReg.coef_)
```

When printing out the shape of both X and Y it is `(5, 157673)` (after putting `u` 4 more times in the Y array, since it would otherwise give the error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 1]`).

However, now I am running into the error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 185. GiB for an array with shape (157673, 157673) and data type float64`.

Why is that? There must be a mistake somewhere and if not, why is it suddenly in the shape of `(157673, 157673)` instead of `(6, 157673)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using scikit-learn's LinearRegression which optimizes with OLS (ordinary least squares). OLS requires a lot of memory.

You should switch to scikit-learn's [SGDRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) which uses stochastic gradient descent (SGD) to optimize. SGD uses far less memory than OLS.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix would be to change the data format - I can't see how your data looks like so my suggestion stay theoretical without example

1. float64 is the most expensive one. using float32 or float16 - depending how much precision point you need. If they are just integer depending on the range you can use even int8 (if less than 255) - use `dtypes` parameters in the `pd.read_csv` function. or convert them later on using `astype`.
2. Timestamp - decides what precision of time is needed - if you are fine with days - don't store hours, minutes and others
3. alternatively usse DataTable https://github.com/h2oai/datatable - Pandas is not the most efficient library when it comes to work with big data. however, I think the first 2 points will fix your issue. Because (157673, 157673) is not too big but 185. GiB sounds too much for it !